# how do you secure database objects in postgres

Tags: postgresql, security, google-cloud-sql

i'm new-ish to postgresql and wondering what are good patterns for securing objects in your databases.

i've been using MSFT SQL server for most of my career, and like the approach that they have taken to securing databases and objects.  Some of the things that I'm missing in postgresql are pre-defined roles at the instance and database levels, such as db_reader and db_writer.

how do you handle security of new objects?

- are you limiting peoples ability to create new objects within the database (of course you are, but i'm interested in an approach or patterns), and how are you doing that (using CICD, manually, event-based triggers)

Currently, i'm using a series of event-based triggers and roles to manage new object creation.  I don't like it though, and feel like its overly complex, but here's the criteria that I used.  I also wanted to avoid others (non-administrators) from having to "escalate their security context", and was hoping to use DEFAULT PRIVILEGES to do this.  Unfortunately, that didn't work for me, which I believe is a result of using a hosted solution, and not having a true SUPERUSER role.

**Overview**

**3 default roles**

- db_reader, read-only access to user-defined databases
- db_writer, read-write access to user-defined databases
- db_admin, full database access to user-defined databases

**Each role inherits the privileges of its “parent”**

- db_writer inherits all privileges of db_reader
- db_admin inherits all privileges of db_writer

**Role-based Privileges**

*Reader role (db_reader)*

- CONNECT on all user-defined databases
- USAGE on all user-defined schemas
- SELECT on all user-defined tables, views, and sequences

*Writer role (db_writer)*

- all privileges associated with db_reader
- INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE on all user-defined tables and sequences

*Admin role (db_admin)*

- all privileges associated with db_writer
- CREATE on all user-defined databases
- TRUNCATE on all user-defined tables

**Two types of roles**

- Group Role (users and permissions)
- User Role (generally personal or application names)
- Privileges are assigned to group roles via GRANT and REVOKE.
- User roles inherit privileges from associated group roles and have the LOGIN privilege.